# Access parents from DataTemplate in external XAML file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an `ItemsControl` that uses a `DataTemplate` which is located in an external **ResourceDictionary.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary ... >
  <DataTemplate x:Key="My_UserControl">
    <local:MyUserControl/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**MyUserControl.xaml** file:

```
<UserControl ...>
   <Button Content="{Binding Path=Test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>         
<UserControl/>`
```

**MainWindow.xaml** uses that template in an `ItemsControl`.
The binding to the Window in `UserControl` doesn't work.

How do I bind from an **external file** like this `UserControl` to any parent, using `RelativeSource` so it works ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=DataContext.Test, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to work. 
I don't think that the `UserControl` is in Visual Tree of the window.

Comment: I was wrong. `VisualTreeHelper` manages to return the window as upmost parent. But the binding still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know why but it started working... Gee...
Either way, your markup is correct.